# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' - pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to run a pandas groupby on my DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd 

# Groupby
cols = ['col1','col2']

df = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False).agg({'r': lambda x: list(x)})
```

Some columns may have `dicts` as values. I attempt to find them and convert to string like this:

```
# Find columns containing dicts
col_dict = [i for i in df.columns if isinstance(dfd[i][0],dict)]
col_dict

# Dict to string
df[col_dict] = df[col_dict].astype(str)
```

How do I groupby a dataframe with columns containing `dicts` data type?

Comment: so what is your question here ?

Comment: @BENY updated the post with q

Answer (score 3):

Given the title and the actual question you asked, I assume you are doing something like the following.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [{"k": 1, "k2": 2}, {"k": 3, "k2": 4}, {"k": 1, "k2": 2}, {"k": 3, "k2": 4}],
        "col2": [42, 88, 86, 75],
        "r": [3.1415, 2.71, 1.121, 0.333],
        "cat": ["a", "a", "b", "b"]
    }
)

df = df.groupby(by=["col1"], as_index=False).agg({'r': lambda x: list(x)})
```

which for me gives the error you mention, `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`.

One way you could do this, as you've started to already, is to convert the dictionaries to strings. Here is how this could be done.

```py
df = df.assign(
    group=lambda DF: DF.col1.astype(str)
).groupby(
    by=["group"],
    as_index=False
).agg(
    {'r': lambda x: list(x)}
)
print(df)
```

which produces

```
               group                r
0  {'k': 1, 'k2': 2}  [3.1415, 1.121]
1  {'k': 3, 'k2': 4}    [2.71, 0.333]
```

As to why grouping by the dictionaries directly raises the error, it seems that under the hood Pandas is using a hash table to create the group keys. Therefore, the values that are used for the group, must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable), which dictionaries are not. Converting them to strings would make them hashable. Another way would be to convert to a frozenset of `(key, value)` pairs, which matches the fact that dictionaries are equal if they have the same set of `(key, value)` pairs, regardless of order (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)).

This actually raises an interesting "gotcha". If your dictionaries happen to have the same `(key, value)` pairs, but in different orders, then converting them to strings may not work as expected. For example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [{"k": 1, "k2": 2}, {"k": 3, "k2": 4}, {"k2": 2, "k": 1}, {"k": 3, "k2": 4}],
        "col2": [42, 88, 86, 75],
        "r": [3.1415, 2.71, 1.121, 0.333],
        "cat": ["a", "a", "b", "b"]
    }
)

df = df.assign(
    group=lambda DF: DF.col1.astype(str)
).groupby(
    by=["group"],
    as_index=False
).agg(
    {'r': lambda x: list(x)}
)

print(df)
```

produces

```
                group              r
0   {'k': 1, 'k2': 2}       [3.1415]
1   {'k': 3, 'k2': 4}  [2.71, 0.333]
2  {'k2': 2, 'k': 1}        [1.121]
```

Notice here that the dictionaries `{'k': 1, 'k2': 2}` and `{'k2': 2, 'k1'}` have the same `(key, value)` pairs but are considered different groups, even though

```py
d1 = {"k": 1, "k2": 2}
d2 = {"k2": 2, "k": 1}
print(d1 == d2)
```

prints `True`

A more robust way to group by dictionaries that would create groups when the dictionaries are equal would be

```py
df = df.assign(
    group=lambda DF: DF.col1.apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.items()))
).groupby(
    by=["group"],
    as_index=False
).agg(
    {'r': lambda x: list(x)}
)
```

Comment: This makes sense. However, we may have multiple columns containing `dicts` and we need to group by all columns except 1 - `r`. I attempt to find cols with dicts `cdict = [i for i in df.columns if isinstance(df[i][0],dict)]`  but it doesn't find all of them because there are `np.nan` at `0th` index.

Comment: You could check the first non-na value with `cdict = [i for i in df if isinstance(df[i].dropna().iloc[0], dict)]`.